# Sign up for membership in Django City, create admin authentication process

Tags: django, authentication

Currently, it is set to return to the first screen of the program when membership registration is completed in Django. However, since anyone can sign up and view information within the program, I want to make it possible to access the program's first page only after the administrator approves it when someone completes membership registration. As a result of Googling, only email verification was found, so I had to ask a question. There seems to be no admin authentication process provided by Django. Are there any similar examples or methods?

Comment: Keeping things simple, you can create a boolean field in your User Model named `access`, Now just change it to `True` whenever someone completes membership registration.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make it possible to access the program's first page only after the administrator approves it when someone completes membership registration.

At first you can set the `step` for every registration level.
and to approve the user to authenticate the page, you can create and check `status` user profile.

Another way is using a django permission for an authenticated page.
you can do this, if the user completed a couple of registration and a `step` number, for example is 7, you can give needed permission to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are you talking about creating the step as custome ?